# Embedding MS.NET C# into c/c++ (like mono)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, mono, embedded-language

Is it possible to embed the MS C# compiler into an umanaged c/c++ host application and make both languages interoperate, very much like Mono does this (like [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Scripting_With_Mono) and [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono))?
I have a working implementation of this für my Qt based C++ Application using mono, but I'm limited (I really need the memory) by the 32bit constraint of mono on Windows (there are no 64bit releases for windows). So can this be achived with "the original" C# implementation?

BTW: I'd like to continue using GNU compilers (mingw-w64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft does support this; their term for it is [hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404385.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to expose host methods to the CLR, just as with mono_add_internal_call ?

Comment: I've never hosted the CLR, so I'm not sure how simple that would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to use C# compiler, then Mono's C# compiler is managed, while Microsoft's C# compiler is native. There are some differences you cannot conquer.

Comment: Fortunately, it is ok to use the Mono managed C# compiler with the Microsoft .NET runtime.